# Compile Qt Project on Windows for Linux / Mac

Tags: qt, compiler-construction, operating-system, mingw, qt-creator

Is it possible to compile a Qt Project **on Windows** for Linux / Mac?

I am using Qt 5.0.2 with MinGW and Qt Creator.

Comment: i think cmake would do the job. There is already a configuration option in QT-Creator. But i never used it though.

Comment: I don't have a `cmake.exe`. Do you know where it is located / I can download it?

Comment: mh, eventually cmake.org

Comment: Did you tried cygwin?

Comment: @DmitrySazonov it is not recognized. I'll try cmake.org today

Comment: @Niklas, cmake it's just a tool that will create "project" files for your IDE. It is not related to any compilation process. But cygwin is an environment extension for windows to run POSIX programs (linux compilers too). Try to google about sudgested tools - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it with compiling and building it on each OS. It is too much effort doing it on Widnows.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not saying it is impossible but it would be really hard. g++ could be tricked into generating object files but there are many linux libraries and headers that just don't exist on mingw.  Linux apps are best built on linux itself.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. Cross-compiling the other way around (on Linux for Windows) is fairly common, despite the lack of "Windows libraries" on Linux.

Comment: So I have to set up a Linux VM / Computer, install QT Creator and compile it there, right? Can I then use the compiled project and execute it on Mac or do I also have to compile it on a Mac?

Comment: @Niklas: Linux and Mac OS X are completely different operating systems, binaries are not compatible. (And it's Qt, not QT.)

Answer (score 1):

For QT 4.* answer is YES, that's possible, I did that ones mainly for 'research purposes' and would not do it again ever.. It takes a lot of time, a lot of hacking bit's and pieces in makefiles, configurations.. There is no ANY practical sense in doing that. It takes 40 minutes to install Linux of your taste on a virtual machine (whatever you prefer) and get proper binaries.

Same applied for MacOSX.. never did it but again I believe it can be done by building a full tool-chain only question what for =))

Answer (score 1):

In our organization we have 1 server with 3 virtual machines that are responsable for cross-platform building. I think that cross-compiling on one real OS may be used only for some kind of learning process, but not for *real* tasks.